# Rspec: click_link in email body

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have feature spec test:

```
describe "Reset password" do
  let(:last_email) { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last }

  it "should be success" do
    # ...
    page.should have_content t("users.passwords.sent")
    last_email.to.first.should eq user.email
    last_email.body.should have_content t("mail.body.recovery_instructions")

    # Here is click_link

    page.should have_content t("passwords.updated")
  end
end
```

How I can click link which is located in `last_email.body` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
link = last_email.body.raw_source.match(/href="(?<url>.+?)">/)[:url]
visit link
```

Comment: Thanks, I added link title to pattern and its works just as expected.